# Asserting array of arrays with JSONPath and spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, jsonpath, mockmvc

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to assert with jsonPath in a JSON document response in spring mvc. Perhaps there's a better way of accomplishing this than using jsonPath for this particular scenario. I would like to validate that the links array has a  rel item of "self" and that "href" attribute of the object of "self" also has an "href" attribute which is equal to "/". The JSON response looks like this:

```
 {  
   "links":[  
      {  
         "rel":[  
            "self"
         ],
         "href":"/"
      },
      {  
         "rel":[  
            "next"
         ],
         "href":"/1"
      }
   ]
}
```

I tried this where I can see that it has rel [0] has self but I would prefer to not rely on where in the links array and rel array the self is and actually test what that href is at links[rel][self] is "/".
Any ideas?

```
 @Before
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(welcomeController).build();
  }

  @Test
  public void givenRootUrl_thenReturnLinkToSelf() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.links[0].rel[0].", is("self")));
  }
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

How about adding several **andExpect** methods? Something similar to:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.links[0].rel[0]", is("self")))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.links[0].href[0]", is("/"));
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do this without hardcoding the array indices (in case the order is different)?

Comment: Kevin, you can use regexp in your jsonpath, like this $.links[?(@.rel =~ /.*self/i)] or something like this. Please, check full documentation here: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Comment: This approach won't work for HashSet because the order of elements is not deterministic

Answer (score 10):

I guess you could do it like this if you don't want to hardcode array index value

```
MockMvc.perform(get("/"))
.andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.links[*].rel").value(Matchers.containsInAnyOrder(Matchers.containsInAnyOrder(Matchers.is("self")))));
```

Answer (score 7):

The [Accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29624993/2940265) looks alright to me. But I am not familiar with junit4. Therefore I will add here how I would test a typical scenario using Junit5.

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
    .andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.links", hasSize(2)))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.links[0].rel[0]")
        .value("self"))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.links[0].href[0]")
        .value("/"))
```

I will here add static imports(in case of a beginner) because when first I was working of I had to figure which imports within several imports.

```
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasSize;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
```

Hope this is helpful for someone. especially someone new to unit testing :)

Answer (score 2):

you can try :

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.links[*].rel[*]", containsInAnyOrder("self")))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.links[*].href[*]", containsInAnyOrder("/")))
```

Answer (score 1):

I know a very old post and you have probably figured it out already, but for the **sake of new devs** wondering this question, like me.

You can use the following.

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItem;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasSize;
.......AdditionalCode
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.path").isArray())
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.path").value(hasSize(2))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.path").value(hasItem("self!"))
```

Source => https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-test-how-to-test-a-json-array-in-jsonpath/